# having with match and group_concat in mysql

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I' trying to write a MYSQL query which looks for a string in an aggregation of fields.

The following query finds all the concatenations where "io sono" is present:

```
SELECT chapter, GROUP_CONCAT(text_search) AS aggregated_chapters
FROM bible_it_cei_2008
GROUP BY chapter
HAVING aggregated_chapters LIKE '%io sono%';
```

However, trying to use MATCH... AGAINST instead of LIKE:

```
SELECT chapter, GROUP_CONCAT(text_search) AS aggregated_chapters
FROM bible_it_cei_2008
GROUP BY chapter
HAVING MATCH ( aggregated_chapters ) AGAINST ( '+"io sono"' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

returns the error:

```
#1210 - Incorrect arguments to MATCH
```

Isn't there any way to use MATCH AGAINST with GROUP_CONCAT?

Answer (score 0):

> Isn't there any way to use MATCH AGAINST with GROUP_CONCAT?

No. That's not the way [FULLTEXT search works in MySQL](https://www.percona.com/blog/2013/03/04/innodb-mysql-full-text-search-in-mysql-5-6-part-2-the-queries/).

If your table contains the columns `chapter` and `text_search`, and you hope to find the values of `chapter` matching text search, you want something like this.

```
SELECT chapter, 
       MATCH(text_search) AGAINST ('+"io sono"' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE) AS score 
  FROM bible_it_cei_2008
```

To get this to work you'll need to create an [appropriate FULLTEXT index](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-index.html).